# jquery programming

Tags: jquery

I have one parent div and multiple of inner div and I want to apply a event at all but get output from only one div.tried on jquery
I am also use boolean values and flags idea but not right way.

Pls guide me
thanks

Comment: what event you want to apply ?

Comment: Please include the code that you are having problems with too... It'll  help if we can see what you are doing...

Comment: Is this a real question or a **troll**??

Answer (score 1):

Then you should use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind handlers on the parent for the children

```
$(parent_selector).on(event_type,descendant_selector,function(){
    //the stuff you want to happen
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you are binding something like a click event to a parent and a child div, and when clicking on the child div both events get triggered? If so, this is because the click event is bubbling up to all parent elements. To avoid this you must use the jQuery stopPropagation() function in the event that is called when clicking on the child div. see here for more details: http://api.jQuery.com/event.stopPropagation